# Same Query, Same Server, different database query runs super slow

Tags: sql, sql-server

Wrote a view in a database. The view takes 0 seconds to run when called from 1 database and 2.5 minutes when called from another.

I have created a video that best describes this problem. Watch it here: https://youtu.be/jEqI2bUyelQ

I tired to re create the view by dropping it. 
I tried to compare the query execution plans, they are different when run with 1 database vs the other. 
I looked into the query it self and noticed that if you remove the where clause the performance is regained and it takes the same amount of time for both.

Expected results are that it should take 0 seconds to run from no matter what database the view is being called from.

Here is the SQL script:

```
SELECT 
    cus.MacolaCustNo,
    dsp.cmp_code ,
    count(distinct dsp.item_no) AS InventoryOnDisplay,
    (SELECT max(dsp.LastSynchronizationDate)
    FROM Hinkley.dbo.vw_HH_next_Capture_date ) AS UpdatedDate,
    case
        WHEN DATEADD(DAY, 90, isnull(max(dsp.LastSynchronizationDate),'1/1/1900')) >= 
            (SELECT max(dsp.LastSynchronizationDate)
                FROM Hinkley.dbo.vw_HH_next_Capture_date ) 
            THEN 'Compliant'
        WHEN DATEADD(DAY, 90, isnull(max(dsp.LastSynchronizationDate),'1/1/1900')) <= 
            (SELECT max(dsp.LastSynchronizationDate)
            FROM Hinkley.dbo.vw_HH_next_Capture_date )
            AND DATEADD(DAY, 90, isnull(max(dsp.LastSynchronizationDate),'1/1/1900')) >= getdate() 
            THEN 'Warning'
        ELSE 'Non-Compliant'
    END AS Inventory_Status
FROM 
    Hinkley.dbo.HLIINVDSP_SQL dsp (nolock)
INNER JOIN 
    [DATA].dbo.vw_HLI_Customer (nolock) cus
        ON cus.CusNo = dsp.cmp_code
WHERE 
    cus.cust_showroom = 1
    AND 
    cus.active_y = 1
GROUP BY cus.MacolaCustNo,dsp.cmp_code
```

Comment: Nobody is going to watch a youtube video of your sql server performance problem. Instead you should post the table definitions including indexes and the query. My guess it stale statistics or even more likely is improperly indexed tables.

Comment: Verify the indexes are the same on the tables in both databases, and rebuild (with fullscan) the indexes on the slower database if so. Also look at the number of rows returned in each... if one returns a dozen, and the other returns a million, yeah, it's going to be slower.

Comment: Becouse you said that it has the same data then i will guss that it has something to do with the db settings like `miscellaneous` and how the data is saved in the table. Compare the two databases settings and is if it right.

Comment: Views are compiled the first time they are run.    You might just need `option (recompile)`.

Comment: This is why I made the youtube. Not to be lazy. Because it is impossible to explain. It is not that the indexes are different on 2 databases. The databases dont have the same tables. The select statement joins data from 1 to the other. So to simplify running this statement select * from Hinkley.dbo.vw_HH_Display_Status from database 1 RUNS IN 0 seconds and running the exact statement against ANY OTHER Database except database Called DATA tables 0 seconds. Running from DATA database takes 96 seconds!

Comment: @Be05x, first of all I'd get rid of an cortesian product. As I can see you use capdate only for getting `max(NextCaptureDate)`, so why not to use subquery `...>=(select max(NextCaptureDate) FROM vw_HH_next_Capture_date)` instead of joining this view?

Comment: @Dmitry tried that. No change!

Comment: Re "it is impossible to explain" - then it is impossible to solve either :) Let's try - do you claim that running exact same simple query, using only three-part table/view names, takes different amount of time if current database changes? Then you likely have plan cache problems; run your select with recompile option in database, where it is slow.

Answer (score 0):

Check the compatibility level between yours databases.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/view-or-change-the-compatibility-level-of-a-database?view=sql-server-ver16

If it is different, leave both databases at the same compatibility level and try again.